# looking for svn merge request application like gitlab or github that can support new merge request and do merge by the repo maintainer

Tags: svn, review, merge-request

Are there any open source softwares that can support such function?
here is my svn management requirements:

1. a developer call Mike commits sth to A branch
2. Mike creates a new merge request,which source branch is A and target
   branch is B
3. the maintainer of branch B settles Mike's merge
   reqeust,generally,appove or not
4. Mike's committing to A merged into B or not